# How to ignore/skip empty rows/lines in CSV file using php?

Tags: php, csv

I have a column of email addresses in a CSV file. I want to check if the email domain exist. 
I read the file using array as follow:

> ```
> $domain = substr($arr[$line][$column], strpos($arr[$line][$column], '@') + 1);   
> if  (checkdnsrr($domain) !== FALSE){
>     echo $arr[$line][$column]. "    -->    Domain valid <br>";
> }
> ```

The code works but how to ignore those lines which are empty in between?
I get this line printed :

```
Warning: checkdnsrr(): Host cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trials\exist.php on line 18
```

Comment: How do you read the file?

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (!empty($domain) and checkdnsrr($domain) !== FALSE) {

 }
```

Comment: Now i am getting an error on the first line of my code:
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 on line ...

Comment: Whats the line in question?  It may be best to employ both this method and the method Hanky Panky suggested in the initial reading of the file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `array_filter()` to remove empty elements from the array:

```
array_filter($arr[$line]);
```

note: it should be an array inside of this array_filter function.